# link to relationship name in has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i have a has_many through relationship. these a the models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :apartments, through: :bookings

end

class Apartment < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :bookings
 has_many :users, through: :bookings
end


class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :appartment

end
```

Table structure:

```
def change
    create_table :bookings do |t|
      t.integer :appartment_id, :null => false
      t.integer :user_id, :null => false
      t.datetime :booking_date 
      t.timestamps
    end
   end
```

show user view

```
- @user.bookings.each do |booking|
                %ul
                  %li
                    Refnr.:
                    = booking.ref
```

How do i add the link to the apartment (name attribute) to the each loop?

I tried

```
= booking.apartment_id
```

but the i get the ID (db record) and i want to show the name of the apartment.

Thanks..
remco

Comment: have u tried the solution mentioned in answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print the name of apartment associated with booking, you can try this:

```
= booking.apartment.name # If you are sure, each booking is having apartment associated with it.

= booking.apartment.try(:name) # Else you should handle the exception also.
```

Comment: If you are not sure that a booking will always have an appartment associated with it, you can use `booking.appartment.try(:name)` to display its name if it exists.

Comment: @MrYoshiji: u r right, otherwise it will show exception if there is no apartment associated , i have updated the answer.

Comment: I think you should post both alternatives and explain each one @AmanGarg ;)